# Infinite loop when having many to many relation Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using .NET 7, I try to get all data from `partenaire` table, with all its related data (many-to-many).

I have these 3 classes:

```
namespace Kollofid.Core.Entities
{
    public class Partenaire : AuditableBaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string? Fax { get; set; }
        public string? Email { get; set; }

        public Guid? CountryId { get; set; }
        public Country? Country { get; set; }
        public string? City { get; set; }
        public string? PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string? Address { get; set; }

        public string? TaxRegistration { get; set; }
        public string? NumeroRegistreCommerce { get; set; }
        public string? Note { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ActivityPartenaire>? PartenaireActivities { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<PartenaireProductLine>? PartenaireProductLines { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<PartenaireHSCode>? PartenaireHSCodes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PartenaireDetailsBancaire>? PartenaireDetailsBancaires { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<Guid>? Activities { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<Guid>? ProductLines { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string? CountryName { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Kollofid.Core.Entities
{
    public class Activity : AuditableBaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public bool Visible { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ActivityPartenaire> PartenaireActivities { get; set; }

        public Activity()
        {
            Visible = true;
        }
    }
}

namespace Kollofid.Core.Entities
{
    public class ActivityPartenaire
    {
        public Guid PartenaireId { get; set; }
        public Partenaire Partenaire { get; set; }
        public Guid ActivityId { get; set; }
        public Activity Activity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the infrastructre `AppDbContext` declaration

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.AppendGlobalQueryFilter<ISoftDelete>(s => s.DeletedOn == null);

    builder.Entity<ActivityPartenaire>().HasKey(pa => new { pa.ActivityId, pa.PartenaireId });
    builder.Entity<PartenaireProductLine>().HasKey(pa => new { pa.PartenaireId, pa.ProductLineId });
      
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
}
```

And finally in `ProductRepository`:

```
private IQueryable<Partenaire> GetAllAsQueryable()
{
    return _dbContext.Partenaires
                     .Include(x => x.PartenaireActivities)
                     .Include(x => x.PartenaireProductLines)
                     .Include(x => x.Country)
                     .Select(par => new Partenaire
                             {
                                 Id = par.Id,
                                 Name = par.Name,
                                 PhoneNumber = par.PhoneNumber,
                                 Fax = par.Fax,
                                 Email = par.Email,
                                 Address = par.Address,
                                 City = par.Address,
                                 PostalCode = par.Address,
                                 TaxRegistration = par.TaxRegistration,
                                 NumeroRegistreCommerce = par.NumeroRegistreCommerce,
                                 Note = par.Note,
                                 CountryId = par.CountryId,
                                 CountryName = par.Country.Name,
                                 PartenaireActivities = par.PartenaireActivities.ToList(),
                                 // ProductLines = par.PartenaireProductLines.Select(prod => prod.ProductLineId)
                             });
}
```

When I call `GetAllAsQueryable.ToList()` I have an infinite loop, I got now exception, and no message on the screen.

When I comment out `PartenaireActivities` and `ProductLines`, I got the data back

I tried to fill `Activities` only with `Guid`, but I have the same problem.

Can someone tell me what the issue is?

I also added this

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are mixing entity relationships with projection, When it comes to projection, don't mix entities with projections.

You're also mixing in a method intended to return back and `IQueryable<TEntity>`. This is a common repository pattern I use but that should just be something like:

```
private IQueryable<Partenaire> GetAllAsQueryable()
{
     return _dbContext.Partenaires;
}
```

You should not be attempting to project the data into new class instances or such when returning an IQueryable. EF will be expecting to continue applying further filtering and such against it and a `Select(x = new TEntity)` will almost certainly throw a few wrenches in the works. If a method like this is in the same class as what is consuming it, that's pretty pointless, just use the DbContext.

If your view only needs a subset of data, define a simple view model to represent that data. Don't reuse an entity object to cherry-pick data. An instance of an entity class should represents a complete entity from the data source. If you need some of that data for a view, create a ViewModel. So for a start you can simplify the query to:

```
var results = _dbContext.Partenaires
    .Select(par => new PartenaireViewModel
    {
        Id = par.Id,
        Name = par.Name,
        PhoneNumber = par.PhoneNumber,
        Fax = par.Fax,
        Email = par.Email,
        Address = par.Address,
        City = par.City, // <- bug here, had par.Address
        PostalCode = par.PostalCode // and = par.Address here too.
        TaxRegistration = par.TaxRegistration,
        NumeroRegistreCommerce = par.NumeroRegistreCommerce,
        Note = par.Note,
        CountryId = par.CountryId,
        CountryName = par.Country.Name

        // PartenaireActivities = ??
        // ProductLines = ??
    });
```

Eager loading using `Include` is not needed when using projection. (`Select`)

So now for the Activities and product lines. What data do you want to display for the Activities? Work that into the projection. For instance if you want the ActivityId and Name available, and only want the activities that are Visible:

```
        // ...
        PartenaireActivities = par.PartenaireActivities
            .Where(pa => pa.Visible)
            .Select(pa => new PartenairActivitiesViewModel
            {
                ActivityId = pa.ActivityId,
                Name = pa.Activity.Name
            }).ToList();
```

Then similar for the ProductLines. Define a simple view model for what your view needs and project those down.

You will encounter various issues when attempting to pass entity references to the view engine. While you were projecting a Partenaire entity down into a copy of the class, your code to try and populate the Activities and ProductLines was just setting references to the actual real entities from the DbContext, which would include references back to the real Partenaire and so-forth. Projecting to a ViewModel avoids these issues and produces better queries with fewer side-effects, but you have to commit to projecting the whole way down and not setting an entity reference even if you think "well what's the point if it has the exact same fields as the entity?"